# What is the output shape after filter concatenation in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For example, Imagine that we have an input tensor of shape `(n,n,48)`, we apply three set of convolutional filters with output dimensions of `(n-4,n-4,16)`,`(n-2,n-2,32)` and `(n,n,48)`. Now what is the output shape if we apply filter-concatenation on the result? and further more how is the concatenation done?

Comment: My guess so far is that it concatenates the image by depth, and keeps the smallest dimensions for other axises that is `(n-4,n-4,16+32+48)`, but in some slides it seemed to me that the author expects an output that sums up the filters.

Comment: One can only concatenate tensors that have some dimensions equal, in this case it doesn't seem you can concatenate at all, what source are you using?

Comment: I'm looking at inception models,
Here is the lecture I'm looking at:
[link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/321/lec/W06/convnets.pdf).

It uses 4 different branches, with different convolution kernel sizes. So the output size should also vary in the first two dimension.

Comment: No, you use padding to maintain the output dimensions all the same, else you cannot do concatenation. Just look at some implementation of it and you'll see the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matias commented, outputs of filters are padded as needed since the final size ( width x height ) of all concatenated layers should be the same.

The largest output in your example is `(n, n)`. Outputs smaller than this should be padded to `(n, n)`. In this case the final (concatenated) tensor size will be `(n, n, 16+32+48) = (n, n, 96)`